# How to prepend scss files in Vue3 + dart-sass?

Tags: vue.js, sass, prepend, dart-sass

I am trying to prepend scss files to my project. Here is my `vue.config.js`:

```
const {defineConfig} = require('@vue/cli-service');
module.exports = defineConfig({
    transpileDependencies: true,
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            scss: {
                sassOptions: {
                    content: "~@/assets/styles/base/_colors.scss;"
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But scss is not loaded (look at the screenshot). I am using Vue3, sass@1.32.7, sass-loader@12.0.0
[image]
[image]

P.S. with node-sass it worker fine

Comment: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders

Comment: using additionalData does not make changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My vue.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "./src/style/global.scss";`,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Works fine for me

Comment: What is your sass-loader version? Do you use dart-sass (not node-sass)?

Comment: I'm using sass@1.49.9 and sass-loader@12.6.0

Comment: I'm not sure why but I noticed I have the same error if I change a variable without re running the server, have you tried re running your front server after making sure your variable is well declared ?

Comment: that is the first time i'm running the project and i didn't change variable name + i re-runed project more than 20 times)

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help i did this with node-sass in my webpack config:

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      env.production ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'vue-style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          url: false,
        }
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          additionalData:`
          @import "css/base/colors.scss";
          @import "css/settings.scss";
          @import "css/font-definitions";
          `
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

With that I can use any of the variables defined from the files in additionalData in vue files.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm using the next code, this appears in the documentation of VUE CLI [GotoDocumentationVueCLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders)

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      // pass options to sass-loader
      // @/ is an alias to src/
      // so this assumes you have a file named `src/variables.sass`
      // Note: this option is named as "prependData" in sass-loader v8
      sass: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/variables.sass"`
      },
      // by default the `sass` option will apply to both syntaxes
      // because `scss` syntax is also processed by sass-loader underlyingly
      // but when configuring the `prependData` option
      // `scss` syntax requires an semicolon at the end of a statement, while `sass` syntax requires none
      // in that case, we can target the `scss` syntax separately using the `scss` option
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "~@/variables.scss";`
      },
      // pass Less.js Options to less-loader
      less:{
        // http://lesscss.org/usage/#less-options-strict-units `Global Variables`
        // `primary` is global variables fields name
        globalVars: {
          primary: '#fff'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The response have the cita to the real documentation.....